# jQuery plugin timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm encountering a strange issue when I reference a third party jQuery plugin in my page  and directly underneath if I have some inline javascript code, the inline code within the page is never hit/fired.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.rateit.js" /> 

//This is never executed!!!
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
   alert("Foo");
});
</script>
```

The third party plugin is jQuery RateIt - http://rateit.codeplex.com/, version 1.0.9 of this plugin.

Using jQuery version 1.9.1.

Can someone explain why the inline code is never fired? Is it that the plugin is timing out?

I can confirm the jQuery RateIt and jQuery scripts are referenced and loading OK. When debugging (using FireBug) and setting a breakpoint within RateIt plugin, this is executed ok. It just seems to escape the code as soon as it's finished with the RateIt plugin.

One thing to note is if I move the reference of the RateIt plugin to AFTER my inline Javascript code, everything appears to work fine.

Example:

```
//This works ok   
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
   alert("Foo");
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.rateit.js" />
```

Comment: Do you see some error in the firebug console?

Comment: Try using `></script>` to end the rateit line instead of `/>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<script>` tags are not self-closing. You have to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.rateit.js"></script>
```